# Text colors in navigations bar is not correct in Xamarin Form iOS implementation

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I do have Android and iOS aplication made in Xamarin Forms.
In android implementation everything looks as expected.

I do have following code in my `AppShell.xaml`

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />

        <!--
        Default Styles for all Flyout Items
        https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyoutitem-and-menuitem-style-classes
        -->
        <Style Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style Class="FlyoutItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="White" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--
        Custom Style you can apply to any Flyout Item
        -->
        <Style Class="MenuItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="White" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
```

But my problem is, that colors do not seem to be correct in iOS. Here is the comparative picture [image]

You can see that navigation back button is **blue** color, navigation title is **black** and input box description is **blue**. On android it is either red or white.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have `<Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />` line in your `<ResourceDictionary>`?

Comment: @adamm yes I do have the style there. I will edit the code in my post.

Comment: Where is color "Primary" defined?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
```

from `<ResourceDictionary>` and adding them in Shell definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestShell.Views"
       Title="TestShell"
       ForegroundColor="White"
       TitleColor="White"       
       x:Class="TestShell.AppShell">

    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
```

Comment: that indeed helped for title bar. But I do not understand why, can you please explain? Unfortunately, it did not help for other controls like Input or dialog window. Is it possible to override color globally?